# How to check if a json string is valid or not in JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have tried :

```
function isJSON(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

To check weather a string is json or not. It returns true for boolean type formats.

Is there any possible way to identify a valid json string in Java Script or in JQuery?

Comment: what do you mean by boolean type formats?

Comment: He means `isJSON(false)` returns `true`.

Comment: Yeah you were right Jeremy Thille

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To assure you have a valid json you must have a string first

```
function isJSON(str) {

    if( typeof( str ) !== 'string' ) { 
        return false;
    }
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function works, just add a boolean check :

```
function isJSON(str) {

    if(typeof(str) === "boolean"){ return false; } // or if(typeof(str) !== "string")

    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```